# Generating new raster by combining the values of two separate ones in Python

Tags: python, raster, raster-calculator, rasterio, band

I have two rasters in the same coordinate system and the same resolution which I am trying to combine in Python using a specific formula. I managed to replicate this in QGIS by going to `Raster -> Raster Calculator`.

However, I am lost when trying to implement this in Python as I don't really know which might be the best approach.

The formula is:

```py
New_Raster = sqrt(sqrt(Raster_1)) * sqrt(Raster_2)
```

Each raster has 1 band and there is no missing data; I am building this in Python because it's a pipeline that will run whenever a new set of rasters is added (they will always have the same characteristics: 1 band, no missing data, same coordinate system and same resolution).

Comment: How many bands do the rasters have? contains no data value?

Comment: I updated the question: no missing data and each raster has 1 band

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this script.

```py
import rasterio
import numpy as np

# CHANGE paths
file1 = r"c:\path\to\raster1.tif"
file2 = r"c:\path\to\raster2.tif"
output = r"c:\path\to\outout.tif"

with rasterio.open(file1) as raster1, rasterio.open(file2) as raster2:
    # read bands
    band1 = raster1.read(1)
    band2 = raster2.read(1)
    
    # change dtype because np.sqrt returns float
    profile = raster1.profile
    profile.update(dtype=rasterio.float64)
    
    # CALCULATION
    new_raster = np.sqrt(np.sqrt(band1)) * np.sqrt(band2)
    
    # save the new raster
    with rasterio.open(output, 'w', **profile) as dst:
        dst.write(new_raster.astype(rasterio.float64), 1)
```

P.S. Don't use `math.sqrt` function, you get an error. Instead, we used `numpy.sqrt`.

Comment: thank you, that worked perfectly!